# Oracle - Convert string to timestamp

Tags: oracle

I have this timestamp string:

```
'2021-09-07T18:24:25.075+02:00'
```

which should be converted to the following format:

```
'dd.mm.yyyy hh.mi.ss'
```

Got this so far, but the format seems to be unrecognizable by Oracle. Any ideas?

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('2021-09-07T18:24:25.075+02:00', 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh.mi.ss') from dual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes around the literal characters inside the format model and use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` with the `TZH:TZM` format models to match the time stamp (and use `FF` to match the fractional seconds and `HH24` for a 24 hour clock):

```sql
select to_char(
         to_timestamp_tz(
           '2021-09-07T18:24:25.075+02:00',
           'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ffTZH:TZM'
         ),
         'dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss'
       ) AS timestamp
from   dual
```

Outputs:

> | TIMESTAMP |
> | --- |
> | 07.09.2021 18.24.25 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fdd57e88727887b2dfba413376fca0ce)*

---

You asked in comments:

> Gotta deal with an ORA-01830 "Oracle date format picture ends before converting entire input string" error now though. ... That is, when I switch the timestamp string with the column I try to convert

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
select to_char(
         to_timestamp_tz(
           column_name
           DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ffTZH:TZM'
         ),
         'dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss'
       ) AS timestamp
from   table_name
```

Then all the values in the column that do not match your format model will return values of `NULL`. You can use this for debugging and find the rows with invalid data.

I.e.

```sql
select column_name
from   table_name
WHERE  to_timestamp_tz(
         column_name
         DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
         'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ffTZH:TZM'
       ) IS NULL;
```

Comment: Great answer, did the trick! Gotta deal with an ORA-01830 "Oracle date format picture ends before converting entire input string" error now though. Do I need to specify NLS somewhere as well?

Comment: That is, when I switch the timestamp string with the column I try to convert